# Fixing the off-canvas sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I have implemented the off-canvas sidebar template from [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/) in my project and made it fixed in small / medium 'view'. Problem is i'm trying to fix it for xs but it really just disappears.

**How can i make it fixed properly?**

*css*

```
html,
body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
.sidebar-offcanvas, .sidebar-offcanvas a {
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    border: none;
}
/*
 * Off Canvas
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row-offcanvas {
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
        transition: all .5s ease-out;
    }

    .row-offcanvas-right {
        right: 0;
    }

    .row-offcanvas-left {
        left: 0;
    }

    .row-offcanvas-right
    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        right: -50%; /* 6 columns */
    }

    .row-offcanvas-left
    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        left: -50%; /* 6 columns */
    }

    .row-offcanvas-right.active {
        right: 50%; /* 6 columns */
    }

    .row-offcanvas-left.active {
        left: 50%; /* 6 columns */
    }

    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

*html*

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
            <my-notification></my-notification>
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
            <div class="list-group">
                .. omitted
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you were trying with your CSS but your problem is

```
.row-offcanvas-right
.sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -50%; /* 6 columns */
}
```

in combination with

```
.sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This causes the `.sidebar-offcanvas` to be 50% wide and then its right position starts at minus 50%. This causes the element effectively to disappear as it gets pushed out of the screen by its total width to the right. So dependent on what you want to achieve you need to change `right: -50%;` to something else like `right: 0px;` for instance.

Comment: You're right! It did reappear after changing right: -50% to 0, however it doesn't seem to work how i want. I'm probably doing it completely wrong.. I'm trying to have it basically exactly as on the TWB page, but keep it fixed if the page is very long. Currently it just stays at the top if u scroll down..

Comment: As your have specified `top: 0;` in your fixed `.sidebar-offcanvas` it should stay at `0` (relative to the viewport) when you scroll down. If it doesn't check if `top` gets overwritten in your case or if there is a parent element which interferes in another way. From the code you provided your `top: 0;` should be effective so I cannot really tell what your problem regarding that matter could be.

Answer (score 0):

default (via .show on .offcanvas). Offcanvas includes support for a header with a close button and an optional body class for some initial padding. We suggest that you include offcanvas headers with dismiss actions whenever possible, or provide an explicit dismiss action.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).